# How to check for something every tick, but only run a command one time when the condition is met?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm making a Minecraft 1.16 datapack and I need to check if a player is in a certain location. I want to check for that condition every tick and then run a function when it is met.

I'm currently using this command: `execute as @a[x = 10, y = 56, z = 42, dx = 8, dy = 10, dz = 0] run say Passed`
The problem is that when the condition is met, the `run say Passed` part also executes every tick, which is not what I want.

When the condition is met, I want that command to only run once, and not every tick, while still checking the condition every tick.
*But*, I also want the command to be able to run again after a second or so.

Could I do this by checking the condition every tick, then running a function that has a timer that only executes a command if it was previously executed 1 or more seconds ago?

Comment: if im understanding correctly you want it to check every tick but not run every tick the condition is met?

Comment: So you want to continually check if the condition is met until the condition is met and then resume the check when the condition is no longer met?

Comment: If you were making an adventure map or something of that nature, I would advise you to hook a command block to a monostable redstone circuit. But I don't think you can do that in a data pack. I suspect the answer you are looking for involves scoreboards in some fashion, but I don't know enough about how they work to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: @Topcode Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: @randomuser922 Pretty much yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make a scoreboard that stores a timer, that counts down to 0 and once that 0 is hit, the command can be run again
setup:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Timers dummy
```

so you'll run these functions each tick:

```
execute if score FunctionX Timers matches 1.. run scoreboard players remove FunctionX Timers 1
execute if score FunctionX Timers matches 0 run execute as @a[x = 10, y = 56, z = 42, dx = 8, dy = 10, dz = 0] run function <namespace>:passed
```

and in passed.mcfunction

```
scoreboard players add FunctionX Timers 20
say passed
```

this will make the command run only every 20 gameticks